# How is the alignment of .data and .bss determined

Tags: c, memory-management

The alignment of .data and .bss is sometimes 4 bytes and sometimes it is 32 bytes.
Example 1: As per the last column in below output the alignment of bss and data is 32 bytes

```
bash-3.00$ readelf --sections libmodel.so
There are 39 section headers, starting at offset 0x1908a63c:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
...
  [25] .data             PROGBITS        01e221e0 1e211e0 26ca54 00  WA  0   0 32
  [26] .bss              NOBITS          0208ec40 208dc34 374178 00  WA  0   0 32
...
```

Example 2: As per the below output the alignment os .data and .bss is 4 bytes

```
bash-3.00$ readelf --sections ./a.out
There are 28 section headers, starting at offset 0x78c:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
...
  [22] .data             PROGBITS        0804956c 00056c 000034 00  WA  0   0  4
  [23] .bss              NOBITS          080495a0 0005a0 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
...
```

what determines the alignment for .bss and .data? Why is it sometimes 4 bytes and at other times 32 bytes?

Comment: Data alignment is a compiler implementation detail.  Why does this matter?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @lsk I am trying to reduce  the size of the .bss segment of my application so that it consumes less memory on a resource constraint host. I would expect .bss to be equal to summation of sizes of all uninitialized objects defined in the global space. But even if i reduce the size of an object by 8 bytes there is no reduction in the size of the .bss. The symbol table does show that the object size has reduced by 8 bytes but there is no change in the .bss size.   There are 10,000 such objects but when i reduce the size of of the class by 8 bytes i don't see any change in the .bss.

Answer (score 0):

I think those different align values were determined by respective `ld` scripts.

- For `libmodel.so`: `section .data align=16, section .bss align=16`
- For `a.out`: `section .data align=4, section .bss align=4`

Comment: Since the `libmodel.so` data clearly states 'Al 32' in the last column, it would seem that the specified alignment would have been specified as 32 rather than 16,

Comment: Both the .data and .bss sections in libmodel.so have been aligned to 32 bytes. e.g, for .data section, the address is 01e221e0 ,it means the last five LSB bits have been set to zero. In other words, it aligns with 32bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it sometimes 4 bytes and at other times 32 bytes?

Once an executable is loaded into memory, it is addressed via process virtual addresses. The alignment constraints are due to virtual address addressing. For example, if you look at the man page for [elf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/elf), check out the description for sh_addralign. This is the reason why different elf objects specify different alignment requirements. You can experiment by changing the source for a.out to include a double and see if the alignment changes.

Note: This applies to memory alignment only. There is an alignment restriction for the actual on-disk file as well. Why? I am thinking this would be to help ease of mapping file data to in-core structures post reading the file in. Others can correct me if I am wrong here.

Update: Would like to clarify one issue. The virtual address alignment is necessary only because of the underlying memory access granularity enforced by the chipset. So, the same program compiled for different architectures may lead to diff alignment restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really nice book, that will give you a great understanding of not only your question, but everything related to it.

The website of the book is [here](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/)

Chapter n. 7 is the one you are looking for.

I don't know if you want a straight answer, or a more sophisticated one, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For bss the alignment is decided using size of data types, if it is not aligned then linker first align the variable address where the bss start can be placed.